# counting the number of digits in using only scanf in c

Tags: c

I need to limit the input from a user to only positive values, and count the number of digits in that number. The user will only type in a (+/-) whole number up to 9 characters long.

I'm only allowed to use the scanf function and for, while, or do-while loops.(I saw in similar questions how to do this using getchar, but I can only use scanf). I'm not allowed to use arrays, or any other library besides stdio.h and math.h

I know that if I write:

> n=scanf("%c%c%c%c%c",&a,&b,&c,&e,&f);

n will count the number of successful scanf conversions.

The problem i'm having is that when I define the input with char, it does everything I want except that the user MUST enter 5 characters. So if the user wants to input "55" he has to press "5" "5" "enter" "enter" "enter".

I need the program to move on after the first "enter" but also be flexible to receive a number up to 9 digits long.

again, I can't use getchar or anything fancy. Just the really basic stuff in C that you learn in the first 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scanf to read the number into a `long int` , then use a for loop with a /10 to count the number of digits

What do you want the program to do in case of a -ve number being entered?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    long int a;
    int b;
    do
    {
    scanf ("%ld",&a);
    if(a<0)
        printf ("invalid input");
    }while(a<0);

    for(b=0;a!=0;b++,a=a/10);
    printf("%d",b);
}
```

(does not handle -ve numbers specially)

Comment: thanks, this is what I needed. negative numbers will prompt an "invalid input" print and will return to loop.

Comment: Updated the code to give you the invalid input prompt. If you are not allowed to use an if condition, replacing the if condition with a while loop is easy enough

Comment: i can use if condition. is there supposed to be a semicolon after the for condition? thanks a lot!

Comment: yup, the semicolon is supposed to be there after the for. think what would happen without it

Comment: it does not work properly; try to feed it with a big int, like `12344444444444444445434345555555555555`, or with a non-number, like `ddd`, or a ten digits number... or, magic, with `0`... the result will be wrong; there are two flaws to be fixed.

Comment: @ShinTakezou OP wanted it only to work for numbers of upto 9 digits. (and it works with 10 digit numbers as well). 0 is a trivially fixed case

Comment: @nofe add a special case for 0, since it will show up as 0 digits currently

Comment: both fix are trivial, sure. But I am happy to have not attended lessons that made me do such homeworks.

Comment: technically those are two bugs. The other is an unitialized variable (`long int a = 0`). Once you fix that, you will discover that special handling of `0` will give `1` even if the input is `ddd`. Then you need another fix to handle the case of "no conversion possible". I write this just to be sure beginners do not learn to disregard these "details"

Comment: @ShinTakezou I dont see why a needs to be initialized, since its being input by the user.

Comment: since when scanf can't parse a single digit, it won't touch a

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char buffer[10] = { 0 };
  size_t len;

  scanf("%9[0-9]", buffer);
  for(len = 0; buffer[len] != 0; len++) ;
  printf("%zu '%s'\n", len, buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

works, but I don't know if it fits your need.

**EDIT** (bits of explanation)

You can replace `size_t` with int (or unsigned int), though `size_t` is better. If you do, use `%d` or `%u` instead of `%zu`.

The basic idea is to exploit a feature of the format of scanf; the `9[0-9]` says the input is a sequence of up to 9 char in the given set i.e. the digits from 0 to 9.

The `for(...)` is just a way to count char, a simple implementation of a `strlen`. Then we print the result.

Comment: remove it, it is not used (including a header does not meant to use it... at first I used strlen, then changed it into the for loop when I've realized that you could not use it)

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take would be the following.

1. Loops are allowed, so go ahead and set one up.
2. You need to have a variable somewhere that will keep track of what the current number is.
3. Think about typing out a number, one character at a time. What needs to happen to the current_number variable?
4. You need to stop the loop if a return key has been pressed.

Something like this should do for starters, but I'll leave the rest up to you, specifically what `return_check(ch)`, `update_state(current_val)` and `char_to_int(ch)` looks like. Also note that rather than use a function, feel free to put your own function directly into the code.

```
int current_val=0;
int num_digits=0;
char ch="\0"

for (num_digits=0;return_check(ch) && num_digits<=9;num_digits++)
{
  fscanf("%c");
  current_val=update_state(current_val);
  current_val=current_val+char_to_int(ch);
}
```

As for the logic in update_state(), think about what happens, one character at a time, if a user types in a number, like 123456789. How is current_val different from a 1 to a 12, and a 12 to a 123.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap a loop around it, something like (I don't know if all of the syntax is right):

```
const int max_size=9
int n=0; //counter for number of chars entered
char a[max_size-1];
do {
    scanf(%c,&a[n]);
    n++;
} while (a[n] != '\r' && n<max_size)
```