# How to calculate length of an integer in C Programming?

Tags: c

Kindly let me know the easiest way to calculate number of digits in an integer.
The scenario is i'll be taking an input from the user which will be a long integer. If the length of the integer is equal to 11 then a message is displayed successful else it shows an error message. Lastly if it gives an error message I would like to break the program and no other instruction should be shown on the screen.

I have tried the code below doing it so far with while and if statements, program does runs but not gives the output that is required.

```
printf("Enter your Account Number :\n");
scanf("%ld", &accno);

while(accno != 0)
{
    ++count;
    }
    count = count;
if (count == 11){
        printf("You are existing customer of bank.");
    }else{
        printf("Sorry you are not a customer of our bank");
    }
```

Comment: Why cannot you make it a _string_? Would be easy to operate on.

Comment: `while(accno != 0)
{
    ++count;
    }` is an infinite loop

Comment: 11 digits may not fit into a `long`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [counting the number of digits in using only scanf in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982737/counting-the-number-of-digits-in-using-only-scanf-in-c)

Comment: `count = count;`..what is this?

Comment: `int i=0; while((n/=10)>0) i++;` something like this

Comment: @SouravGhosh It's a well-known technique to guard against the effect of [Cosmic Rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray#Effect_on_electronics) ... if you get the timing right, you take the old, correct value (`count`) then assign it back to the original variable _just after_ a cosmic raw has altered the value :-)

Comment: @TripeHound well, then, make it better, no? `int var, var1, var2, var3, var4; var1=var2=var3=var4 = 5; var = (var1 == var2)?var3:var4;`

Comment: @TripeHound How this technique will help if this line is optimized right away by any decent compiler (unless `count` is volatile)? Actually I am not sure how serious your statement is...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Run it on multiple processors like SpaceX does.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You choose whether to optimise for _speed_ (`-O3`), _size_ (`-Os`) or _cosmic ray protection_ (the in-development `-Ocrp`).

Comment: `int digits = floor( log10( fabs( accno ) ) ) + 1;`

Comment: @JohnBode `log10( fabs( 0 ) )` is a problem case.

Comment: `digit_count = 0; do { digit_count++; accno /= 10; } while(accno);`  Reports 1 when `accno == 0`.  Handles all negative values too.

Comment: @chux: yeah, a sanity check for 0 will need to be done beforehand.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1: Math**

There's actually a mathematically smart way to find the number of digits in any number, using the `log` function (base 10):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int numlen(unsigned long long n){
     if(n==0) return 1;
    return (int)(ceil(log10((double)(n)))); //sorry for the multiple castings, as ceil/log both take in and return doubles
}
```

This method is of course slower, but it's mathematically beautiful.

EDIT: I fully agree with @chux comment that this method, due to the castings and floating point precision problems, is not the most preferable for integer solutions. However, it is still the most mathematically appropriate way of solving the problem, imo.

**Method 2: Loops**

```
int numlen(unsigned long long n){
    int len = 0;

    if(n<10) return 1;
    while (n) {
        n /= 10;
        len++;
    }
}
```

**Method 3: Recursion**

Refer to @Rutendo answer for recursive-based answer

**Method 4: Just check? (your application only)**
Since all you need is a way to check if the number is 11 digits long, just check if the integer is between 10000000000 and 99999999999 inclusive.

```
int isElevenDigits(unsigned long long n){
     if(n>=10000000000 && n<=99999999999) return 1;
     else return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good point! Edited!

Comment: The problem is that `log10` takes in a `double` by default, so sometimes it'll throw an error if you don't do a force casting

Comment: *facepalms* - edited thanks

Comment: Should you care for other details:`unsigned long long n; ... (double)(n /* not x */)` --> the cast to `double` incurs rounding for large `n` as `n` is 64-bit and `double` typically past 54 bits rounds.  So `9,999,999,999,999,999,999` is exact as `unsigned long long` yet when converted to `double` becomes exactly 1.0e+19 and then is off by 1 for this task.  Using FP math for an integer problem tends to run into a host of unsuspecting corner cases and is best avoided for integer problems.